# How to hanlde snoflake failover to diffreent account with respect to JDBC url

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I was going through the snowflake documentation about
Snowflake Database Replication and Fail-over.
I will be pointing to Snowflake table using JDBC from our application which is on EC2(AWS).

If in case there is a outage in snowflake account and we have to switch to different account/region do i have to change the URL ?

It says below four benefits but do we have to do changes in our application to point to new snowflake account /region

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/snowflake-launches-database-replication-and-failover/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in general you would need to change the url.

In theory you could connect to Snowflake via a proxy and have the proxy switch from the primary to secondary if the primary stopped responding.